# Softsign derivative 1/(1+abs(x))^2 not drawn correctly at the 2009 latexlive version tikz, pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, texlive

I want to draw 1/(1+abs(x))^2 in tikz. At home I have the new latexlive version installed and everything looks fine. At work I do not have the new latex version because Ubuntu 12.04 still includes the old version from 2009 in the repository. With the old version the graph has a "bump" around the y-axis.

Does anyone know a workaround?

```
\documentclass{paper}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot[black, smooth] {1/(1+abs(x))^2};
         \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

[image: Picture of the Bug]

Comment: Please provide a minimum working example or the Harkonnens will come and get you.

Comment: Try `\addplot[black,samples=3000,restrict y to domain=0:3] {1/(1-abs(x))^2};`

Comment: @Jake Actually I didn't run it but I was hoping the bump reappear for even numbers of samples. From your comment I guess it didn't happen.

Comment: @Jake: Leaving the smooth option did not help. It only makes the bump more edgy. A higher sampling rate also did not yield the wished result.

Comment: @percusse: This results in the error "don't know key restrict y to domain..."

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: Which example do you need? :-)

Comment: @MuadDib You should have provided all the LaTeX source that is required to compile the source, including `\documentclass` and so on. Providing the information saves others a lot of work because they don't have to type in these commands. Also it shows you've done some "research".

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: I just changed that and added a picture. This code compiles withe result in the picture!

Comment: Is it not possible to update the computer at work? If you have not the rights ask the admin to do it! That would be the best solution in my opinion ...

Comment: @Jake: Does not help. Just yields a higher resolution of the plot pictured above.

Comment: The TeXLive in Ubuntu 12.4 will _never_ be upgraded - that's a _feature_ (12.4 is _stable_), not a bug. If you want the latest TeXLive, either update your OS or use vanilla TeXLive.

Comment: @MuadDib Good man MuadDib. (Who is Usul among us?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*See below the answer for the updated question with `1/(1+abs(x))^2` including workaround methods for older installations.*

### `1/(1-abs(x)^2`

Three variants:

1. Unmodified example:
   The form of the curve has artefacts of option `smooth`.
2. The domain is limited to get a closer look at point (0,1).
3. Larger scale.

**Remarks:**

- Instead of option `smooth`, the sampling rate can be increased. Default for option `sample` is 25. See [percusse's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133568/softsign-derivative-1-1absx2-not-drawn-correctly-at-the-2009-latexlive-ver#comment301667_133568). On the downside the runtime and file size increases with higher sampling rates.
- With an even value for `sample`, the symmetry gets lost, the right peak becomes smaller. See [Jake's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133568/softsign-derivative-1-1absx2-not-drawn-correctly-at-the-2009-latexlive-ver#comment301668_133568). Therefore the example below uses odd values.
- Restricting the y domain helps in avoiding `! Dimension too large` errors. See also [percusse's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133568/softsign-derivative-1-1absx2-not-drawn-correctly-at-the-2009-latexlive-ver#comment301667_133568).
- Since the y domain is unlimited, the examples make use of `ymax` to cut off the peaks instead of having closed peaks.

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a3paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
      \addplot[black, smooth] {1/(1-abs(x))^2};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[samples=1001, restrict y to domain=0:6, ymax=5]
      \addplot[black] {1/(1-abs(x))^2};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[samples=1001, restrict y to domain=0:1500, ymax=1000]
      \addplot[black] {1/(1-abs(x))^2};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### `1/(1+abs(x))^2`

The following example shows the unmodified plot with option `smooth`. It shows again, that option `smooth` is not the best choice for functions with sharp corners. The version below uses an increased sampling rate without option `smooth`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
      \addplot[black, smooth] {1/(1+abs(x))^2};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[samples=1001]
      \addplot[black] {1/(1+abs(x))^2};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Workarounds for older installations

- Update TeX installation, packages. Sometimes this is not possible or wanted.
- It can be tried, whether an updated version of `pgfplots` solves the problem.

  1. Create an empty directory and put the TeX test file there.
  2. Download [`pgfplots.tds.zip`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/install/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots.tds.zip).
  3. Unpack it without directories in the scratch directory:

     ```
     $ unzip -j pgfplots.tds.zip
     ```
  4. And run `pdflatex` on the TeX test file.
- If the previous step succeeds, `pgfplots.tds.zip` could be installed in a local or home `texmf` tree.
- Otherwise

  1. create a standalone file with the right fonts and font sizes, the problematic plot on the first side without headers and footers, e.g.:

     ```
     \documentclass{article}
     \usepackage{tikz}
     \usepackage{pgfplots}
     \pagestyle{empty}
     \begin{document}
       \begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}
     \end{document}
     ```
  2. Then go to a different computer with a recent TeX installation and generate the PDF file. (Or a friend can do it for you.)
  3. The margins are cropped with `pdfcrop`, for example.
  4. The cropped image is included via `\includegraphics` in the original document.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately I put the wrong function in my code. I want to plot 1/(1+abs(x))^2 with a plus sign in the denominator.
I edited this some minutes in my original post.
With this function the plot of tikz does not correspond with the real plot found here: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F%281%2Babs%28x%29%29%5E2

Comment: @MuadDib Be careful. It gives identical results. `\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[ymin=0]
            \addplot[samples=1001,domain=-1:1] {1/(1+abs(x))^2};
         \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}`. Don't smooth a curve with cusps and nonsmooth properties, you change it's values graphically not numerically so it gives you a completely different curve. Because graphics driver tries to smoothen out no matter which formula leads to that curve.

Comment: @Jake: He has *both* problems. Therefore I have also added a section about possible workarounds.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: I will probably just insert the plotted graph with \includegraphics. Unfortunately turning smoothing off does not remove the bump described above. Thanks Heiko for your help.